# rvest Wikipedia-Scraping: Dealing with Inline-Reference Numbers

Tags: r, rvest

I am struggling with small inline reference numbers when scraping wikipedia tables with rvest. They seem to be included in a class called "sup", but I cannot remove them in the process of scraping.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
read_html("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergebnisse_der_Landtagswahlen_in_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland") %>% 
          html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[10]') %>%
          html_table() %>% 
          .[[1]]
```

In the example above, note for example the small "1s" in the first and second row of the first column.

[image]

When reading in the table with rvest's html_table, the "1s" are attached to both the beginning and end of the string. The same applied for the 6th and 7th column.

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.
Greetings,
Marcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the solution. It is to manually remove the span classes containing the little reference numbers in the table. Works perfectly.

```
raw <- read_html("https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergebnisse_der_Landtagswahlen_in_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland") 

spans <- raw %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*/tr/td/span")

xml_remove(spans)

raw %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[10]') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]
```